# Getting "Missing Right Parenthesis" error using CASE WHEN in query

Tags: sql

I am using "CASE WHEN" in the query to fetch value for either this or that condition. I am getting "Missing Right Paraethesis" error. Please tell me where the query is to be tuned.

```
SELECT * FROM MNDTRY_NODE_COND
 WHERE (MNDTRY_NODE_COND.OPTN_CD IN 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS  
    (SELECT * FROM MNDTRY_NODE_COND
      WHERE MNDTRY_NODE_COND.OPTN_CD IN ('GAN','4BB','RFF','U32','VVT','OAP')) 
    THEN ('GAN','4BB','RFF','U32','VVT','OAP') 
    ELSE ('*') END);
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I don't think you're allowed to do `WHERE SomeColumn IN CASE ... END`.

Comment: Hi, I am just validating the table whether the given input value (here the input values are 'GAN','4BB','RFF','U32','VVT','OAP') has records or not. If it available, assign the given input values to condition or assign '*' value to the condition

Comment: @ All.. The above query is working when i give only single value in THEN part(.... THEN ('GAN').....) but not for more than one value. Is there any decoding should be used in THEN part?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * 
FROM MNDTRY_NODE_COND 
WHERE OPTN_CD IN ('GAN','4BB','RFF','U32','VVT','OAP')
union all
SELECT * 
FROM MNDTRY_NODE_COND 
WHERE OPTN_CD = '*'
and not exists (SELECT * FROM MNDTRY_NODE_COND WHERE OPTN_CD IN ('GAN','4BB','RFF','U32','VVT','OAP'))
```

Comment: @ RedFilter, My scenario is validating the table whether the given input value (here the input values are 'GAN','4BB','RFF','U32','VVT','OAP') has records or not. If it is available, assign the given input values to condition or assign '*' value to the condition. So the final resultset should either for "'GAN','4BB','RFF','U32','VVT','OAP" values or for '*' value. Not union of both!

Comment: Thats correct your query is giving correct resultset only. One more question, please check out my query and i want to assign a value either ('GAN','4BB','RFF','U32','VVT','OAP') or ('*') to where condition "MNDTRY_NODE_COND.OPTN_CD" based on the data available scenario. How to do that?. Because i just need to apply the solution in another complex query's where condition part.

Comment: The above query is working when i give only single value in THEN part(i.e. THEN ('GAN') ) but not working for more than one value. Is there any decoding should be used in THEN part?